# Entity framework CodeFirst : Multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I know the question has been asked multiple times but none of the answer was clear enough to understand what is going wrong with entity when adding an object to a collection of another one.

I started entity with a code first approach. Here is my code:

```
        var user1 = new User("user1");
        var user2 = new User("user2");

        context.Users.Add(user1);
        context.Users.Add(user2);

        // Followers
        user1.Followers.Add(_followerAccessor.CreateFollower(user2));
        context.SaveChanges(); // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE
```

Classes

```
public class Follower
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission FollowerPermissions { get; set; } 
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Events = new List<Event>();
        Followers = new List<Follower>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // One to Many
    public virtual ICollection<Follower> Followers { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool CanDoSmthg { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about the definition of the `Events` reference in the constructor of `User`? You need too show ALL the parts of your model. Also, why did you named `FollowerPermissions` plural when its not even a collection?

Comment: Thank you Yorro. The model was limited to that because it was attempt to resolve the problem. You are right I should have called the class 'Permissions'.

In the meantime, I have found a work around to this problem. I just need to create a follower object within the Context.Followers and then assign the user I want to. Instead of doing both things at once.